# Angularjs app not loads on first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When I load the index page it redirects to the login page. After login the index.html will appear. But when I assign the scope variable in the angular app, it does not reflect for the first time. If I refresh the page again, it reloads. Confused a lot in this sceneraio. Guys please anyone help.

Below I mention the app.js which does not load for the first time after login.

```
app.config(
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
        // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

        $stateProvider
            .state('dsn', {
                url: "/dsn",
                templateUrl: "design_and_selection.html",
                controller: "Design_Controller"
            })
    }
)

app.controller("indexController", function($scope, $http, $window, $location, $stateParams, GetHostUrl, $state, $timeout, $rootScope, $localStorage) {
    //$rootScope.loggedInUserName = $localStorage.userName;
    $scope.loggedInUserName = $localStorage.userName;
    $scope.getnotification = $localStorage.getnotification;


    $scope.count = "";
    if ($scope.getnotification) {
        $scope.count = $scope.getnotifications.unread;
        if ($scope.count == 0) {
            $scope.count = "";
        }
    }
    console.log($scope.count);
    $scope.clicker = 1;
    $scope.headernotifi = function() {
        $scope.clicker = 0;
        $scope.count = "";
    }
    if ($scope.getnotification) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.getnotification.notifications.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.getnotification.notifications[i].message == "Conversation Reviewing") {
                $scope.getnotification.notifications[i].getreviewer = "review";
            }
            if ($scope.getnotification.notifications[i].message == "Conversation Approved") {
                $scope.getnotification.notifications[i].getreviewer = "approve";
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.getnotification.notifications.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.getnotification.notifications[i].updateTime) {
                var c = $scope.getnotification.notifications[i].updateTime;

                $scope.getnotification.notifications[i].gettime = "c";
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-app="communicator">
    <div id="loginDiv" ng-controller="indexController">
        <a class="notify" ng-click="headernotifi()" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="not-value1" ng-class="{'not-value': count > 0}" ng-cloak>{{count}}</span>
        </a>
        <div class="container" ui-view style="min-height:600px;"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to get atleast $scope.count in index.html at first time.

where,

```
$localstorage.getnotification = {
    "notifications": [{
        "id": 2786,
        "message": "Conversation Approved",
        "name": "CC Test vel",
        "raisedBy": "reviewer",
        "status": 0,
        "updateTime": "2017-01-27 20:48:56.0",
        "user_role": "Reviewer"
    },
    {
        "id": 2492,
        "message": "Conversation Approved",
        "name": "Prepaid Card Activation for No Transactions",
        "raisedBy": "Reviewer",
        "status": 0,
        "updateTime": "2017-01-19 18:50:04.0",
        "user_role": "Reviewer"
    }],
    "unread": 2
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please use proper code indents so people can read your code. There are tools in question editor for formatting code. Also be more specific about what is or isn't working properly

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks.. Edited

Comment: I'm actually surprised index.html loads at all, since you don't have a route to it, and your `otherwise` sends everything to `/login`.  I can tell you that on first load, it's trying to reroute to `/login`, so if you don't have that page set up, then that would be why nothing loads.

Comment: I routed the index.html in login.js it redircts to $state.go('dashboard'); @ChrisStanley

Comment: after login i used the below code.. if($localStorage.loggedIn == "True"){
             $(".login-footer").hide();
            $(".header").show();
            $(".footer").show();
           $state.go('dashboard');
        }

Comment: am showing the header using jquery.. in the header part only.. the count need to apply

Comment: If you're using Angular, stop using jQuery.  You should be using scope variable and `ng-if` or `ng-hide` or `ng-show` for showing/hiding elements.  STOP.  USING.  JQUERY.  Seriously.  Stop it.  Stop it.  Stop it.  Instead of using jQuery, figure out how to do it in Angular.  Because what's the point in using a framework, if you're not going to learn how to use it the right way?  So here's a tip for you:  STOP USING JQUERY.  Also, I highly recommend that you do one other thing:  STOP USING JQUERY.  I realize those are the same things, so I'll leave you with this:  STOP.  USING.  JQUERY.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks.. Sorry as a beginner i did some mistakes. Will not use jquery in future. Is there any solution to solve this now.

Comment: The problem is that because you're using jQuery, it's breaking the model, which means that your Angular app doesn't see that the variable has changed from false to true.  That's why you have to refresh the page.  If you change it from jQuery, it should work.

Here's an example, but not 100% related, since I don't see any div with the class `login-footer` in your posted code:

    `<div class="login-footer" ng-show="loggedIn">
        ... code ...
    </div>`

Then in your controller:

    `$scope.loggedIn = $localStorage.loggedIn`